# CTRL+R in shell - if I go past the command I want, how do I get back to it?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, shell, search, command-history

I'm feverishly hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to find some command I used awhile ago, when suddenly I get to it. By reflex, I continue hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, passing it for something further back in the shell history. How do I go back to the command I just passed, without having to start the whole search over?

Comment: ctrl+s is **supposed** to search forwards (according to `man bash`), but apparently that doesn't work on Mint or Ubuntu :/ [Bash history search, partial + up-arrow](http://askubuntu.com/q/59846) might be relevant for a different solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> functionality to search *backwards* through shell history is provided by the [Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library used by Bash.  The corresponding function to search *forwards* through the history is, by default, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

However, the problem is that the terminal driver already uses this key combination for **flow control**: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *stops* or pauses text being printed to the terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> *resumes* the flow of characters sent to the terminal device.

These settings are turned on by default for most terminal devices on GNU/Linux systems with the result that Bash/Readline never sees the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key sequence since it’s caught by the terminal driver and never passed on to the shell.

This behaviour (also termed *XON/XOFF flow control*) can be disabled by running:

```
stty -ixon
```

Now the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key combination will be passed through to Bash/Readline.

#### Alternative key combination

If you’d prefer Readline to use a different key combination for searching *forward*, use the `bind` command to enable a different key binding, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (for Forward). *NB: all the quotes are required.*

```
bind '"\C-f": forward-search-history'
```

#### Modify configuration to keep these changes

Terminal flow control isn’t particularly useful on modern devices so I would advocate running the following command whenever a new terminal or pseudo-terminal device is started:

```
stty -ixon
```

`.bashrc` would probably be a good start-up file to run this command as the file is sourced for interactive Bash shells. If `.bashrc` is not sourced by `.profile` or `.bash_profle`, the above `stty` command should be added to whichever start-up file is used for login shells.

The Readline configuration file is `.inputrc` if you prefer to use a different key binding such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search *forward* through history:

```
bind "\C-f": forward-search-history
```

#### Related links

- [The TTY demystified, Linus Åkesson](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)
- [Interesting historical perspective from Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12146/22812)
- [Software flow control, Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)
- [What is the point of Ctrl-S?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s)

Comment: What is the purpose of editing the Readline config, if that key combo is the default?

Comment: @Andrew  When I first wrote that, I wasn't 100% sure that this was the default key combination. I thought it possible that `Ctrl-S` was a configured by the majority of distribution package maintainers so I included the Readline configuration file for completeness. I'll edit it out as it's not necessary and makes the answer longer than it needs to be.